# st_ino st_mode giving wrong values

Tags: c, unix

i am writing a program to print certain file/dir info of all the files/dir of the given directory

here is the code

```
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int i;
    struct stat fileStat;
    dir = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (!dir)
    {
        printf("cannot open directory : %s\n",argv[i]);
        exit(1);
    }

    entry = readdir(dir);
    while (entry)
    {
        stat(entry->d_name, &fileStat);
        printf("%ld ",(long)fileStat.st_ino);
        if (S_ISLNK(fileStat.st_mode))
        {
            printf("lnk");
        }
        else if (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode))
        {
            printf("dir");
        }
        else if (S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode))
        {
            printf("reg");
        }      
        printf(" %s\n", entry->d_name);
        entry = readdir(dir);
    }
```

i have checked what could be the possible reason for st_ino giving wrong values. the only thing i found was to typecast it to long. done that. still giving wrong output.
can you tell me why?
here is the output i am getting

```
937896 dir .
937896 dir grade.m
937896 dir grade
914091 dir ..
914091 dir maze
914091 dir myWork
914091 dir grade.d
914091 dir hello.d
```

Comment: You're failing to check the return code of `stat` which would probably tell you it's not finding the files.

Comment: any reason why it would not be able to find the files?

Comment: That's explained in the dup linked. The `d_name` field only contains the file/directory name, not the path. Unless you pass in "." as a directory, your code is bound to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stat()` call is returning an error, because you are calling it on a file name with no directory path but the file is not in the current directory.  You should always check for an error from the `stat()` call, and then you would have noticed the issue immediately.